# Generic Create Model Mutation for Graphene

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create some kind of a generic create mutation in graphene for a flask application. In order to create a mutation, the syntax would normally be as follows:

```
class CreateMutation(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        model_attribute1
        model_attribute2
        ...

    def mutate(root, info, model_attribute1, model_attribute2):
        create model here
```

I would like to create some kind of generic create mutation class. To do so, I would need to dynamically create the Arguments class and then pass those into mutate. I've figured out I can get attributes we need for the mutation from the sqlalchemy model with `SqlAlchemyModel.__table__.columns`, but I am having trouble figuring out how to create the Arguments class given these columns.

Comment: you should create a function `create_class` that returns a class Arguments, and then assign class.Arguments = create_class()

Comment: also, use `type(classname, inheritance, attributes)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

````
def create_class(args: dict[str, str]):
    class Arguments: pass
    for arg in args:
        setattr(Arguments, arg, args[arg])
    return Arguments

x = create_class({'thing': '100'}); assert x.thing == '100';```
````